# Ruby twitter gem: How to provide user login?

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I want to use the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) for my application. With my own oauth_token / oauth_secret it works fine, but now I want to establish the possibility for user sign in. In the gem documentation I can not find a hint for my problem. As I am using sinatra, I don't want to use twitter-login. (Should I?)

How can I provide the possibility to sign in? / How can I provide user specific oauth_token and secret?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why not use the twitter-login gem?

Comment: Thought it would only be for rails, but obviously I'm wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: The Github page says something about Sinatra, so you should probably be fine. But i must admit i have never used it.